# Feature Extraction for landscape images

Tags: feature-selection, similarities, image-processing

I work on a landscape-image database (forests, beaches, landmarks, cities etc.) and I'm trying to find the similarity between them, I don't have labels or any specific classes, I just want to find pairs of the ones that have the most similarity. (the beaches that look like the most, or the cities that look alike etc) So far I have been using the GIST Descriptor without much success and I would like to try something different for feature extraction. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance, I appreciate any help!